# Expo firebase 7.9.0 can't get downloadUrl

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

My method does manage to load the image from expo to firebase storage but I can't seem to get the download URL.

```
const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
const uniqid = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
const ext = uri.split('.').pop(); // Extract image extension
const filename = `${uniqid()}.${ext}`; // Generate unique name
const response = await fetch(uri);
const blob = await response.blob();

var ref = firebase
  .storage()
  .ref()
  .child('images/' + filename);
ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => console.log(url));
return ref.put(blob);
```

};

Here is the error I get

```
FirebaseStorageError {
```

"code_": "storage/object-not-found",
"message_": "Firebase Storage: Object 'images/gebwu7tnh.jpg' does not exist.",
"name_": "FirebaseError",
"serverResponse_": "{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
"status": "GET_OBJECT"
}
}"

Comment: Your code seems to generate a unique ID for a filename and then tries to determine the download URL for that ID. It seems very unlikely that a file exists for that unique ID in Firestore Storage, which is why you get an error message.

Comment: Thanks frank you are right I did find s solution I will post soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found that helped me from researching. I did refactor my firebase to use a higher order component. Here is my firebase method.

```
 uploadImageAsync: async (uri) => {
const uniqid = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
const ext = uri.split('.').pop(); // Extract image extension
const filename = `${uniqid()}.${ext}`; // Generate unique name
const ref = firebase
  .storage()
  .ref()
  .child('images/' + filename);
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
  };
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
  xhr.send(null);
});

const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);

blob.close();
const imgUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
console.log(imgUrl);
return imgUrl;
```

},
};

Here is how I implemented it in my component

```
 const setImage = async (uri) => {
try {
  return await firebase.uploadImageAsync(uri);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};